# ExtJS - Textarea widget within rowEditing panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

The ExtJS [RowEditing plugin](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing) does not seem to handle textarea inputs unless they are squashed to the height of the row, which renders them unusable.

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/8SA34/

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [{
        "name": "Lisa",
            "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-111-1224"
    }, {
        "name": "Bart",
            "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1234"
    }, {
        "name": "Homer",
            "email": "home@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1244"
    }, {
        "name": "Marge",
            "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1254"
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        editor: {
         xtype: 'textarea',
         allowBlank: false,
         height:100
        }
    }, {
        header: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textarea',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    }, {
        header: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone'
    }],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
    })],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
});
```

Is there a config fix for this, or an existing plugin?

Failing that, what's the best approach to create a textarea that spills out of the row on focus?

- Extend textarea?
- Extend RowEditing plugin?
- CSS?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that simply with CSS:

```
.x-grid-row-editor .x-panel-body{
    height: 68px !important;
}

.x-grid-editor .x-form-text,
.x-panel-body .x-box-inner{
    height: 60px !important;
}

.x-grid-row-editor-buttons-default-bottom{
    top: 69px !important;
}

.x-grid-row-editor-buttons-default-top{
    bottom: 69px !important;
}
```

Now you can paste text in the field which has more than a single row, but if you want wrap by enter, then you have to overwrite the `onEnterKey` method.

http://jsfiddle.net/8SA34/9/

Comment: That's useful, thx, but part of my requirements are that the rowEditor panel does not grow to accommodate the field. That's what I meant when I said "create a textarea that spills out of the row on focus" in my OP - although I could have been clearer about that. DatePicker, Combo etc. all manage to be single-row height then expand to add content without changing the height of the rowEditor panel. I need a textarea that behaves likewise.